# Java client server program using tcp/ip

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

Im writing a client server java program using TCP/IP stream and my server connects to oracle database. when client request some information, the server process the query i.e returns a column with some rows( say 5). i want to send this entire column back to client, i am able to send and receive single line of data, but not multiple lines( as a table contains many rows i,e lines)....any help is appericated

Comment: You will need to be more specific, post some code, and say exactly what sort of problem you are having.

Comment: my code is huge to be sent here, if I can email you that will be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a collection object and return that object

Comment: I tried to save the column in byte[] format, but still my client reads only first line of byte array not the entire rows

Comment: With the information you have provided, it is a little tough to suggest you anything. If you can atleast post the bit of the code that is used to populated the object that is being returned, there would be some use.

Comment: case 2:
           { 
            ResultSet rset2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT customers1.name,customers2.name,customers1.phone# FROM labdatas11.customers customers1,labdatas11.customers customers2 WHERE customers1.phone# = customers2.phone# AND customers1.cnum!= customers2.cnum");
            while(rset2.next())
            {
    byte[] name1=rset2.getBytes(1);
    byte[] name2=rset2.getBytes(2);
    byte[] name3=rset2.getBytes(3);   
    System.out.println(""+name1+""+name2+""+name3);
out.println(name1);out.println(name2);out.println(name3);
            }rset2.close();
            };break;

Comment: this was my code on server and my client looks like this: case 2:
   {
   String name1=in.readLine();
   String name2=in.readLine();
   String name3=in.readLine(); 
   System.out.println("" +name1 +name2 +name3);
   out.close();
   in.close();
   };break;

Comment: Name1    name2       name3
[B@5d61dfb5[B@44a613f8[B@736921fd
[B@7b36a43c[B@40589e56[B@7a03411a
[B@6ba7508a[B@3598cb3d[B@42472d48
[B@4eedf3f6[B@682bc3f5[B@114e3f41
[B@281acd47[B@779b04e2[B@625dcec6
[B@7cb25b9d[B@219ce060[B@424ecfdd

Comment: this is what i get on client site:                                                         Name1    name2       name3
[B@5d61dfb5[B@44a613f8[B@736921fd

Comment: the first output is on server site and 2nd on client site, what i need to do to send entire column to client insted of only first row

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize you database query result into a string that does not contain line breaks. More over, you can use a well-defined data format, such as [JSON](http://json.org/).

I don't believe that Oracle database returns a data to your server side app in a string representation. Inside your server program, you actually get some database object (possibly, JDBC, if it's Java). How do you turn this object into a string is up to you.